# Java - 2D-array - filling a game table step by step

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find out how I can fill up a game table with chars. The board size is generated by user input. The program asks the user about the number of rows and the number of columns. Later, in the output there should be the numbers for each of the rows appearing as well as for the columns to visualize the game field. An 'x' char should appear (e.g., beginning at field[3][0] given that the user puts in NumberOfRows = 4 and numberOfColumns = 2) until the whole board is filled up with the chars.

This is my code so far:

```
    System.out.print("Number of rows: ");
    int numberOfRows = Input.readInt();
    System.out.print("Number of columns: ");
    int numberOfColumns = Input.readInt();

    char [][] field = new char[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];



        for (int i = numberOfRows-1; i >= 0; i--) {

            System.out.print(field[i]+ " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < field[0].length; j++) {
                field[i][j] = 'x';
                System.out.print(field[i][j]+ " ");

            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

I have 3 questions:

1) How can I assign the value 'x' to my 2D array?
2) How can I get my program to fill 'x' bit by bit and not fill all fields at once?
3) How can I tell the program that it is building (numbering) the game board for me?

Thank you! I am happy about all hints :)

Comment: a) you already assign 'x'. b) you already do it one by one, repeatedly, using the loops. c) how do you want to tell the program that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, the output should look like this:

  1 2
1
2
3
4 x

  1 2
1
2
3 x
4 x

And so on... Until all fields are filled up with 'x' chars...